# Youtube iFrame API - React, Player is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, youtube, youtube-api

I am currently using the iFrame API from my project and I am trying to have custom volume controls so that the user is able to change the volume outside of the iframe video. I have set up the player, but it is always undefined when it's being called outside an eventHandler.

```
  const { youtubeDetails, volume } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  useYoutube(loadVideo);

  let player: any;
  function loadVideo() {
    (window as any).YT.ready(function () {
      player = new window.YT.Player("player", {
         events: {
           onStateChange: onStateChange
         }
      });
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(player)  // never defined
    changeVolume()     
  }, [volume]);

 function onStateChange() {
   console.log(player)  // always defined
 }

  function changeVolume() {
    player.setVolume(volume * 100);
  }
```

This is because loadVideo() is never called again after the very first rerender. Is there a work around this structure so that the goal functionality is achieved?

The custom useYoutube Hooks is as follows:

```
import React from "react";

export const useYoutube = (callback: any) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!(window as any).YT) {
      var tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      firstScriptTag?.parentNode?.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      tag.onload = callback;
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I ran in to the same problem and the problem seems to be that  YT is loaded first and then with a delay the properties 'ready' and 'Player' is loaded.
So I had to wrap my callback in a setTimeout with aproximatly 200ms delay to be able to call the methods 'ready' and 'Player'.